# null launched cancel error in android

Tags: android-emulator

I want to run myApp on emulator but when it starts running emulator it goes slow and throws a null launched cancel exception I have also checked wipe data option and in DDMS alos changed time to 900000 but nothing works for me.Please help i haved searched stackoverflow extensively and tried what people are saying but unablle to install app on emulator.Also checked option for automatically choosing target emulator.

Android Launch!
 adb is running normally.

Performing com.example.googlemap.MainActivity activity launch

Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'newDevice' is not available. Launching new emulator.

Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'newDevice'

New emulator found: emulator-5554

Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...

HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'

Uploading googleMap.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'

Installing googleMap.apk...

Failed to install googleMap.apk on device 'emulator-5554!

(null)

Launch canceled!